# python - deserialise avro byte logical type decimal to decimal

Tags: python, binary, deserialization, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to read an an Avro file using the python avro library (python 2). When I use the following code:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter, BinaryDecoder
reader = DataFileReader(open("filename.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
schema = reader.meta
```

Then it reads every column correctly, except for one which remains as bytes, rather than the expected decimal values.

How can I convert this column to the expected decimal values? I notice that the file's metadata identifies the column as 'type' : 'bytes', but 'logicalType' :'decimal'

I post below the metadata for this column, as well as the byte values (expected actual values are all multiples of 1,000 less than 25,000. The file was created using Kafka.

**Metadata:**

```
 {
                            "name": "amount",
                            "type": {
                                "type": "bytes",
                                "scale": 8,
                                "precision": 20,
                                "connect.version": 1,
                                "connect.parameters": {
                                    "scale": "8",
                                    "connect.decimal.precision": "20"
                                },
                                "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
                                "logicalType": "decimal"
                            }
                        }
```

**Byte values:**

```
'E\xd9d\xb8\x00'
'\x00\xe8\xd4\xa5\x10\x00'
'\x01\x17e\x92\xe0\x00'
'\x01\x17e\x92\xe0\x00'
```

**Expected values:**

```
3,000.00
10,000.00
12,000.00
5,000.00
```

I need to use this within a Lambda function deployed on AWS, so cannot use fast_avro, or other libraries using C rather than pure Python.

See links below:
https://pypi.org/project/fastavro/
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you will need to use the `fastavro` library. Both the `avro` and `avro-python3` libraries do not support logical types at the time of posting this.

Comment: I have now realised I cannot use fastavro, because I need to deploy on AWS and so can only use libraries written in pure Python.

Comment: In that case I think your only option at the moment is probably to fork fastavro and remove the Cython parts. The library has both a python and cython implementation so if you remove the cython parts you should be left with a pure python solution that will work.

Comment: Thank you. Deleting the cpython parts worked perfectly.

Comment: @oli5679 Could you perhaps share your solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to decode the byte string into decimal. This pads the value to the next highest byte structure so all possible values will fit.

```
import struct
from decimal import Decimal

def decode_decimal(value, num_places):
    value_size = len(value)
    for fmt in ('>b', '>h', '>l', '>q'):
        fmt_size = struct.calcsize(fmt)
        if fmt_size >= value_size:
            padding = b'\x00' * (fmt_size - value_size)
            int_value = struct.unpack(fmt, padding + value)[0]
            scale = Decimal('1') / (10 ** num_places)
            return Decimal(int_value) * scale
    raise ValueError('Could not unpack value')
```

Ex:

```
>>> decode_decimal(b'\x00\xe8\xd4\xa5\x10\x00', 8)
Decimal('10000.00000000')
>>> decode_decimal(b'\x01\x17e\x92\xe0\x00', 8)
Decimal('12000.00000000')
>>> decode_decimal(b'\xb2\xb4\xe7\x84', 4)  # Negative value
Decimal('-129676.7100')
```

Refs:

https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.10.2/spec.html#Decimal
https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-characters

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the fastavro package works as default on the same file.
I ended up using the code below. Still not sure if there is a way to address this problem directly using the avro library, or to deserialise the output posted in the question above.

```
import fastavro
with open("filename.avro", 'rb') as fo: 
    for record in fastavro.reader(fo): 
        print(record)
```